# ASP.NET Core: hosting.json urls not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I am trying to override the server url manually with a `hosting.json` file, however the url never get's used. I am on .net core 2.0.

hosting.json:

```
{
  "urls": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio gives you two profiles to run application: 
IIS Express, which fairly obviously runs the application using IIS Express and 
WebApplication2 (or any given name of your app), the name of the web project, which runs the application using dotnet run using Kastrel instead of IIS. 
You can try switching and running application from the second profile (it should pick up hosting.config).

[image: switching]

If you want to run app on IIS you can change launchSettings.json that is located under project properties

[image: IIS]

Also, you can find more details how to configure urls [here](http://benfoster.io/blog/how-to-configure-kestrel-urls-in-aspnet-core-rc2).